# Using connection form for unknown frame field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hodge-theory

I have a way to calculate the connection 1-form $\alpha$ associated to a compact simply connected parallelizable Riemannian surface $(M,g)$ (so, $M$ is topologically a disk) and a special orthonormal frame field $(e_1,e_2)$. Essentially, one starts with an arbitrary orthonormal frame and splits its connection form into $da + \star du$ using the Hodge decomposition. The $da$ part can be removed by rotating the original frame by $-a$. The $\star du$ part solves the equation

$$\Delta u = -K$$

So if you know what $\alpha$ is on the boundary and $K$ is on the interior, you can solve for $\alpha$ on all of $M$. So far so good, and the frame $(e_1,e_2)$ is clearly special. But just having $\alpha$ doesn't tell us what the frame field is, even up to constant rotations or reflections, so we can't directly use it to calculate covariant derivatives.

My question: given knowledge of $\alpha = \star du$, is it possible to either compute $(e_1,e_2)$ (I doubt there is a practical way to do so) or otherwise use $\alpha$ to compute covariant derivatives? Also, has anybody studied this type of frame? It's hard to believe that nobody has tried this before.

I've already calculated an example for a spherical cap, in which case $e_1$ and $e_2$ could be understood as directions of latitude and longitude. That's the only nontrivial example I have where I know what $(e_1,e_2)$ are.